# How to deal with "optional interfaces"?

Tags: oop, interface

"Optional interface" is probably not a standard term, so let me give an example. Suppose I have:

```
interface Car {
  start();
  honk();
}
```

Now I can have like `HondaCar`, `PriusCar`, etc., implementations. Yay! But what if honking is not all that important to me or my users, so I decide to do something like this:

```
interface Car {
  start();
  canHonk(); // return true if honking is supported
  honk(); // undefined behavior of canHonk is false
}
```

So this is what I'm calling an "optional interface", because actually supporting honk is optional. It still seems like a fine, well-defined interface, but another way you could've expressed this is by separating this into two interfaces:

```
interface Car {
  start();
}

interface Honkable {
  honk();
}
```

Now, if user code really needs to do some honking, you must pass it a `Honkable`. If it's optional, it can take a null pointer. And if it doesn't care about honking at all, it can ignore `Honkable` completely. However, this does put more onus on the user code to manage all this.

So, I've listed some pros and cons that I see, but I'm curious what others think. Which is the preferable pattern in which situations?

Comment: If you implement an interface, you **MUST** implement every method of the contract. If you only need parts of the interface for specific implementations, then you have a bad abstraction and should separate your interface into multiple interfaces (sort of how you did above with `Honkable` and `Car` as two separate interfaces).

Comment: "But what if honking is not all that important to me or my users...", then don't implement it. Adding a bool method doesn't ease the dependency on honking for the people not interested in it. It just *another* method they won't be interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Composition over Inheritance**, our subject here, is an important OOP principle. It tells us to define our objects by their functions. Which means, your second approach is the best practice. Do it like:

```
public class SomeCar: ICar, IHonk {}

public Interface ICar {}

public Interface IHonk {}
```

> *Design for capability instead of identity.*

Answer (score 2):

Two separate interfaces is the way to go in my opinion

If you want to honk, implement the interface

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, separate interfaces are a better solution here. It is also worth noting that it conforms to the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

However, another approach would be to use a feature container:

```java
public class FeatureContainer {
    // ...

    public bool isAvailable<T>() {
    // ...
    }

    public T getFeatureOrNull<T>() {
    // ...
    }
}
```

and then have for example:

```java
public abstract class Car : FeatureContainer {
// ...
};

public class SomeCar : Car {
    public SomeCar()
    : base(/* instantiate all implementations of supported interfaces */)
    {}
}
```

so then you could have:

```java
Car aCar = getSomeCar();

if (aCar.isAvailable<Honkable>()) {
    Honkable h = aCar.getFeatureOrNull<Honkable>();
    h.honk();
}
```

This can have of course numerous syntactical variations depending on language and desired semantics.